# Segfault at err() (from err.c) when called from python ctypes

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I wrote a python wrapper around libbgpdump using ctypes but it segfaults when libbgpdump calls "err()". Here is the C code that fails:

```
if(count > MAX_PREFIXES) {
    err("too many prefixes (%i > %i)", count, MAX_PREFIXES);
    return MAX_PREFIXES;
}
```

When I replace err() with printf() it works.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
#0  strchrnul () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchrnul.S:34
#1  0x00007ffff6f2ba60 in __find_specmb (format=0x3fa <Address 0x3fa out of bounds>) at printf-parse.h:99
#2  _IO_vfprintf_internal (s=0x7fffffffc660, format=0x3fa <Address 0x3fa out of bounds>, ap=0x7fffffffce68) at vfprintf.c:1335
#3  0x00007ffff6f311a4 in buffered_vfprintf (s=0x7ffff729d1a0 <_IO_2_1_stderr_>, format=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>) at vfprintf.c:2313
#4  0x00007ffff6f2bbde in _IO_vfprintf_internal (s=0x7ffff729d1a0 <_IO_2_1_stderr_>, format=0x3fa <Address 0x3fa out of bounds>, ap=0x7fffffffce68)
    at vfprintf.c:1316
#5  0x00007ffff6fd4ef1 in __GI_vwarn (format=0x3fa <Address 0x3fa out of bounds>, ap=0x7fffffffce68) at err.c:140
#6  0x00007ffff6fd512e in __GI_verr (status=-177566080, format=<optimized out>, ap=<optimized out>) at err.c:168
#7  0x00007ffff6fd51e7 in err (status=<optimized out>, status@entry=-177566080, format=<optimized out>, 
    format@entry=0x3fa <Address 0x3fa out of bounds>) at err.c:184
#8  0x00007ffff56a4196 in read_prefix_list (s=s@entry=0x7fffffffd010, afi=afi@entry=1, prefixes=prefixes@entry=0xa4d9a4, 
    incomplete=incomplete@entry=0xa527c8) at bgpdump_lib.c:1255
#9  0x00007ffff56a5db8 in process_zebra_bgp_message_update (asn_len=4 '\004', entry=0xa48b20, s=0x7fffffffd010) at bgpdump_lib.c:741
#10 process_zebra_bgp_message (s=s@entry=0x7fffffffd0e0, entry=entry@entry=0xa48b20, asn_len=asn_len@entry=4 '\004') at bgpdump_lib.c:682
#11 0x00007ffff56a6941 in process_zebra_bgp (entry=0xa48b20, s=0x7fffffffd0e0) at bgpdump_lib.c:543
#12 bgpdump_read_next (dump=0x9c2cf0) at bgpdump_lib.c:190
#13 0x00007ffff5b7d4d8 in ffi_call_unix64 () from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
#14 0x00007ffff5b7cee0 in ffi_call () from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
#15 0x00007ffff5b6f311 in _ctypes_callproc () from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
#16 0x00007ffff5b6fa82 in ?? () from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
#17 0x000000000046005e in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#18 0x0000000000467209 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx ()
#19 0x00000000004ab55a in ?? ()
#20 0x0000000000486c3d in ?? ()
#21 0x0000000000491a5d in PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords ()
#22 0x00000000004ebdc7 in ?? ()
#23 0x000000000045fdca in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#24 0x0000000000460227 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#25 0x0000000000467209 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx ()
#26 0x00000000004cfc12 in PyEval_EvalCode ()
#27 0x00000000005137db in ?? ()
#28 0x000000000044cab6 in PyRun_FileExFlags ()
#29 0x000000000044cfca in PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags ()
#30 0x000000000044dd0c in Py_Main ()
#31 0x00007ffff6f0476d in __libc_start_main (main=0x44ddcb <main>, argc=2, ubp_av=0x7fffffffe178, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, 
    rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffe168) at libc-start.c:226
#32 0x00000000004cda7d in _start ()
```

Thanks for any help :)

------------------- Edit ----------------------------

Ah now I see the problem. libbgpdump is using it's own err() function, defined in ./util.c, but when I use the lib from ctypes it tries to use the one from err.h, even though it is never included.

Any advice why this is happening and how to make it work?

Comment: You should read this on how to use the err function: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/err.3.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you are missing one argument of the err function, the returned value (see [err MAN pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/err.3.html)):

```
if(count > MAX_PREFIXES) 
    err(MAX_PREFIXES, "too many prefixes (%i > %i)", count, MAX_PREFIXES);
```

Comment: +1 for missing an argument, but shouldn't the first argument be a return value (argument to `exit()`)?

Comment: Although this is technically the correct answer, the problem is different. See my edit above.